# Serialize List<ICustomClass> to xml?

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization

I have the following code files:

```
public interface IMod
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    string Description { get; set; }
    bool Enabled { get; set; }
    List<IClassFile> ClassFiles { get; set; }
}
public interface IClassFile
{
    string Path { get; set; }
    string FileName { get; set; }
    bool Enabled { get; set; }
}
public class ClassFile : IClassFile
{
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get { return System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Path); } }
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }

    ....
}
public class ZippedMod : IMod
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }
    public List<IClassFile> ClassFiles { get; set; }

    ....
}
public class ConfigurationBlock
{
    public List<IMod> Mods { get; set; }

    ....
}
```

Throughout the course of my program, I add a few `ZippedMod`s to the `ConfigurationBlock`, but now I want to serialize them. I tried doing:

```
using (var stream = new StreamWriter("config.xml"))
{
    var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ConfigurationBlock));
    ser.Serialize(stream, configBlock);
}
```

But I get this error:

```
There was an error reflecting type 'MinecraftModManager.ConfigurationBlock'.
|-Inner Exception:
      Cannot serialize member 'MinecraftModManager.ConfigurationBlock.Mods' of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[MinecraftModManager.IMod, MinecraftModManager, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]', see inner exception for more details.
      |-Inner Exception:
            Cannot serialize member MinecraftModManager.ConfigurationBlock.Mods of type MinecraftModManager.IMod because it is an interface.
```

Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't serialize an interface due to the abstract nature of them. Lots of concrete types can implement the same interface, so it creates an ambiguity. You must use a concrete type.

Comment: But I *have* to use an interface, otherwise the entire program wouldn't work.

Comment: @TheAdamGaskins An interface is nothing more than an abstract base class with pure virtual methods. Why 'must' it be an interface over an abstract base class?

Comment: Ah, misunderstood what you meant by "You must use a concrete type." But will changing the interfaces to abstract classes will magically fix everything...?

Comment: @TheAdamGaskins It's not 'magic', if you use a common (abstract) base class instead of an interface, then the serializer will be able to preserve the correct fully qualified type information of your objects. You can't do that with interfaces. So, it will resolve the issue.

Comment: That seems to have fixed it. Thanks :)

Comment: @TheAdamGaskins Not a problem, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You can't serialize an interface, only a concrete class with the default XmlSerializer. You may be able to implement [IXmlSerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx) to override this behavior.